# Trying to install nacl (native client) from google but getting syntax error

Tags: installation, google-nativeclient

```
C:\nacl_sdk>naclsdk list
  File "C:\nacl_sdk\sdk_tools\sdk_update_main.py", line 720
    print "Native Client SDK Updater, version r%s" % (REVISION,)
                                                 ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "C:\nacl_sdk\sdk_tools\sdk_update_main.py", line 720
    print "Native Client SDK Updater, version r%s" % (REVISION,)
                                             ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\nacl_sdk>
```

This is what I am getting on the command line. I have done nothing to the unzipped folder I downloaded except moving it to the `C:\ directory`. Any advice, solutions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Comment: Thank you Ha. It seems that I hadn't added python 2.7 to the correct Path.